# Plotted function looks different from expected using matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have defined a function and I expect its graph to look like the graph below:

[image]

However, when I try to plot it in Python using matplotlib it looks a little different from what is expected and I have not been able to figure out where it has gone wrong. I thought the reason may be operator precedence in Python, but I think I have included a superfluous number of brackets in so that it should not even matter.

[image]

The specific function I am using to plot it is as follows:

```
def f(x):
    return 50 * (1/(1 + ((50/5) -1 ) * e ** (-max(0, 0.1 * x))))
```

and the entire code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import e

# 100 linearly spaced numbers between -10 and 100
N=200
x = np.linspace(-10,100,N)

def f(x):
    return 50 * (1/(1 + ((50/5) -1 ) * e ** (-max(0, 0.1 * x))))

f_eval = np.zeros(N)
for idx, i in enumerate(x):
    f_eval[idx] = f(i)


# setting the axes at the centre
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# plot the function
plt.plot(x,f_eval, 'r')

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

---

**Edit**: nevermind - only after I had tried to figure this out for hours had and posted the question on here had I realised that the graph was right all along but the y-axis was just drawn differently.

The line that says:
`ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')`

should be changed to:
`ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')`